# How I can union two pdf files using suitescript 2 server side

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to union 2 pdf files, on the server site Netsuite script api2.
Or other native javascript option.
Thanks

Comment: Please share more details and what you tried to do to get clear idea about the problem Make a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Use the pdfset element in a template file. This is a fragment from an SS2 Suitelet:

```
function renderSet(opts){
    var tpl = ['<?xml version="1.0"?>','<pdfset>'];

    opts.files.forEach(function(id, idx){
        const partFile = file.load({id:id});
        var pdf_fileURL = xml.escape({xmlText:partFile.url});
        tpl.push("<pdf src='" + pdf_fileURL + "'/>");
    });

    tpl.push("</pdfset>");

    log.debug({title:'bound template', details:xml.escape({xmlText:tpl.join('\n')})});

    return render.xmlToPdf({
        xmlString:  tpl.join('\n')
    });
}

var pdf = renderSet({files:[file1, file2]});
pdf.name = basename +'_'+ getDateStamp() +'.pdf';

response.writeFile({
    file:pdf,
    isInline: false
});
```